# Issue using Ternary operator in UseState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm trying to do the following

```
    const[name,setName]=useState(recipe!==null?recipe.name:'')
```

The name appears to never be assigned with the ternary operator. Do they just not work within useState?

I've also tried reassigning the name like:

```
    if(recipe!==null){
         setName(recipe.name)
```

I receive an error in the console about too many re-renders.
Is there any other way of assigning name conditionally?

Edit
This is the structure of recipe

```
 const[recipes, setRecipes]=useState([
        {
            id:1,
            name:'Chicken Curry',
            ingredients:"Some ingredients",
            steps:"Some steps",
            energy:'2899',
            fat:'28.5',
            carbohydrates:'41.3',
            protein:'12',
            sodium:'1226',
            preparationTime:'15',
            difficulty:'Easy'
        }
```

How I'm calling the const

```
<RecipeModal recipe={activeRecipe}/>
```

and the recipe modal

```
const RecipeModal=({recipe}) =>{
```

Comment: Share the code snippet for ```recipe```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example, what you showed is not enough for us to understand the underlying issue

Comment: why don't you use spaces?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what is going on there but I will try to help. I guess that the recipe can be undefined instead of null. You could try below:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(recipe ? recipe.name : '');
```

In example above, we are simply checking if the recipe has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value so the default state value will be an empty string if recipe is: null, undefined, 0 or "".

---

Regarding reassigning name state. Are you doing that inside a useEffect hook? Please review all your useEffect hooks to see if you are not changing a value that is present in a dependency array.

Infinite re-renders can be solved by adding an if statement to see if the value we want to assign to did really change. It could be also related to a place where you reassign a recipe. I could help further with a bit more code.

Comment: My original solution left 'name' undefined, your solution appears to always leaves name as ''.

Comment: Hmm, could you log the recipe to the console to see its value? Your solution returned undefined because (I guess): the recipe was NOT NULL and the recipe.name was undefined. I suspect that the issue is somewhere else and the recipe does not contain the expected value.

Comment: I've tried logging the recipe as well as recipe name, and it's printed the correct value each time.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use like this:

```
const[name,setName]=useState(recipe!==null?recipe.name:null)
```

Or if name is string type, then

```
const[name,setName]=useState(recipe!==null?recipe.name: " ")
```